# Ubuntu running on vmware-kvm with Dual Screens

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, multiple-monitors, vmware, linux-kvm

I'm trying to find a way to use Ubuntu 64-bit on vmware-kvm.exe with dual screens. Ubuntu runs perfectly fine but I can't use my two monitors unless I use VMware workstation player. I've been searching online for so long but I still can't find a solution.

I found [someone](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/How-to-use-vmware-kvm-exe-with-Dual-Screens/td-p/1792189) who asked the same question on the official vmware website in 2014 but an admin answered "vmware-kvm currently does not support VMs using multiple monitors. It's certainly something that we can consider[...]".

And a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vmware/comments/80c6gi/multiple_monitors_with_player_kvm/) on r/vmware with only one comment saying it's impossible unless you use VMware workstation.

Also, there's no option for dual monitors when I run `--preferences`.

[image: screenshot of preferences]

So now that I have accepted the fact that VMware-kvm doesn't support multiple monitors. (According to what an admin said in 2014) I'm trying to find another solution. I don't know if the solution is to modify my current setup or if I should just use something else instead of vmware-kvm. I would like to have true full screen (without the top bar appearing when I let my mouse at the top of the screen for too long) and I would like to be able to switch between my host (windows) and my virtual machine (Ubuntu) with a key. I have already found that by editing

```
%APPDATA%\VMware\preferences.ini
```

and adding

```
pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar = "TRUE"
```

The top bar disappear but exiting isn't as simple as pressing a single key, you need to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You also doesn't get the performance of kvm.

Comment: As the person who wrote vmware-kvm and that comment from the VMware community forums, I regret to say that there's still no way to configure vmware-kvm to use multiple host monitors, nor is there a way to switch between host and VM using the VMware Workstation or Player UIs via a hotkey.